# Automorphism of $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ as a ring with respect to different multiplication operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show that the ring $R=\left(\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C},+,\cdot\right)$ with the usual addition operation $+$ and the multiplication:
$$\cdot:\left(\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\right)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C},\ (a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$
is isomorphic to the direct product $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. with the usual addition and multiplication $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ for complex $a,b,c,d$).

I have found that the elements $e_1=\left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2},\frac{i}{2}\right)$ and $e_2=\left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2},-\frac{i}{2}\right)$ are idempotents in $R$ such that $e_1+e_2=1_R=(1,0)$ and are orthogonal to each other. Hence, since $R$ is commutative, we can see that the ideals $I_k=e_kR=Re_k=e_kRe_k$, for $k=1,2$, are rings with unit $1_{I_k}=e_k$ and so we can easily construct and isomorphism from $R$ to $I_1\times I_2$ (as a direct product of rings) as such (from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since they are central idempotents):
$$f(r)=(e_1r,e_2 r)$$
And now I am stuck here. It remains to show that $I_k\cong\mathbb{C}$ for $k=1,2$, but I can't exactly find the isomorphism. I think I am seeing a connection since the product of $I_k$ reminds me of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix}$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, but I can't define the isomorphism correctly. Maybe I am making this harder than it needs to be, so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have ring isomorphisms $R\simeq \mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2+1)\simeq \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-i)\times \mathbb{C}[X]/(X+i)\simeq \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$.

The first one sends $(a,b)$ to the class of $a+bX$, the second is given by CRT and the last one sends $(P \mod X-i, Q \mod X+i)$ to $(P(i),Q(-i))$.

All in all, we get that the map $f: R\simeq \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ sending $(a,b)$ to $(a+bi,a-bi)$ ia a ring isomorphism, and this can be verified directly:

- For bijectivity, note that $f^{-1}$ is the map sending $(u,v)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ to $(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u-v}{2i})$.
- Moreover, $f((a,b)(c,d))=f((ac-bd,ad+bc))=((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i,(ac-bd)-(ad+bc)i)$, and $f(a,b)f(c,d)=((a+bi)(c+di),(a-bi)(c-di))=((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i,(ac-bd)-(ad+bc)i)$.

Hence $f$ is the required isomorphism.

Comment: Ah it was that simple. I had thought of that same isomorphism $f$ but I defined it as $f:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow R$ and it didn't work. Thank you for the insight!